# Verifying the path of a web service resource

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am writing some unit tests for a web service written years ago. The root class has a path like:

```
@Path("v1/path/")
public class RootResource {
   ...
}
```

The methods inside the class have their respective path. One working path is:

```
@GET
@Path("orders/{order_num}.xml")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getXML() {
    ...
}
```

This is working fine at `root_path/v1/path/orders/123123.xml`.

However, there is another method:

```
@POST
@Path("orders/{order_numer}/status.xml")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response getStatusXML() {
  Logger.info(CALLER, "orderStatusXML", "XML Request received");
 ...
}
```

When I try to access this at `root_path/v1/path/orders/123423/status.xml` I get 404 in return. Even the first line with the logger is missing from the logs.

I am on Weblogic 12 and we used Jersey REST API for these web services.

I have tried a number of things to make sure the path listed in the test case is the correct one. Any hints/ideas on how to check for the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for the `root_path/v1/path/orders/123423/status.xml` path to give a 404 unless something else is acting on that URL.

Things to try:

- look into your `web.xml` file and see what URL pattern Jersey handles. That particular URL might be handled by some other servlet;
- again look into the `web.xml` and see if you have [any filters declared](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html). What URLs do does filters intercept and what do the filters do to the request once intercepted?
- this might not be the case but I'll add it anyway... is it a "404 - Not found" that you get back or is it actually a "405 - Method not allowed" that is returned? If you try to access the `root_path/v1/path/orders/123423/status.xml` URL with a GET, like from the browser, you get 405 because your method is annotated with `@POST`. Are you using a POST?

My bet is on a filter!